# Black Screen when using -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I'm so frustrated because I've done this a million times before, but now I can't get a tableviewcontroller to push my detailsviewcontroller. I'm using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and my code is below:

```
 HistoryDetailsViewController *HDV = [[HistoryDetailsViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:HDV animated:YES];
```

All I get in return is a black screen. I just want to be able to go from a table view cell to this view controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your `HistoryDetailsViewController` have any content? And is your layout defined in a storyboard for this view controller?

Comment: Can you see animation when you tap on tableViewCell?

Comment: tableviews are not stupid. they are precious little beings.

Comment: lol, the anger is too much xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `HistoryDetailsViewController` has its layout defined in a storyboard, you need to instantiate the view controller from the storyboard:

```
HistoryDetailsViewController *HDV = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"yourstoryboardidentifierhere"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I'm such an idiot. The following solution is below:

```
 HistoryDetailsViewController *HDV = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HistoryDetails"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:HDV animated:YES];
```

This worked perfectly